# How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: iaik/x509/X509Certificate?

Tags: java, struts2, x509certificate, noclassdeffounderror, iaik-jce

I am using Struts 2.0 for one application and getting the class not found  exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: iaik/x509/X509Certificate
```

After searching some site i found this class is in iaik_jce.jar.Can anyone help me understanding when this jar is required and if the jar is proper

Cannot paste the entire stacktarce.

Comment: Why can't you post the entire stack trace? Is there a `caused by` line in the stack trace?

Comment: If it's "proper"? I'm not sure what that means. *When* (I think you mean "Why") it's required depends on the app-something is trying to use it. You can look at your Maven dependency tree to find out what's requiring it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved adding enttoolkit.jar .

The jar is available with webmethods client `\common\lib\ext\enttoolkit.jar`

The java code is calling service of webmethods,so the jar is required in the java app classpath.